# How to append text to text area created in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, textarea

I have the following code which creates a text area.

```
interface IReceiverProps {
    receivedMessage: string;
    topic: string;
}

export default class Receiver extends React.Component<IReceiverProps, {}> {

    render() {
        var textAreaStyle = {
            width: 1300,
            height: 450,
            border: '3px solid #cccccc',
            padding: '5px',
            fontFamily: 'Tahoma, sans-serif',
            overflow: 'auto',
            marginLeft: '10px'
        }
        return (
            <textarea style={textAreaStyle} value={this.props.receivedMessage}/>
        );
    }

}
```

This received message is passed by another component. How can I append the receivedMessage one below another in this text area? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: some working code? jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: There are few dependencies so its hard to get it there. In the above code, I'm just adding the received message to value of text area. This obviously will replace the message everytime. So how should this be handled? How can I append it?

Comment: how about using a `div` under `textarea` and on saving sending combined data?

Answer (score 3):

Use a state called textMessage.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    textMessage: props.receivedMessage
  };
}
```

In componentWillReceiveProps, append to textMessage.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.receivedMessage !== this.props.receivedMessage) {
    this.setState({
      textMessage: `${this.state.textMessage}\n{nextProps.receivedMessage}`
    });
  }
}
```

Bind to textMessage.

```
<textarea style={textAreaStyle} value={this.state.textMessage} />
```

Comment: I guess there is a problem with this. This will recursively insert text on every change. Someone please confirm..

Comment: @vijayst this wouldn't work if the same value is received for the prop isn't it? I tried removing the condition "if (nextProps.receivedMessage !== this.props.receivedMessage) {" but still doesn't help. The "componentWillReceiveProps" is not getting called when same values are received.  What should be done to handle this?

Comment: wrap the text within an object. `received={{ message: 'your message' }}`

Comment: 2022 Update -> https://ndpniraj.com/blogs/react-js-insert-text-in-the-middle-of-textarea